# How to mock graphql subscription in cypress using mock-socket library?

Tags: graphql, cypress, apollo-client

I am trying to use mock-sockets with Cypress, to mock graphql subscription.
I tried this code but it doesn’t work with Apollo Client because Apollo use ‘WebSocketLink’ instead of 'WebSocket'.

```
import {
    Server,
    WebSocket,
} from 'mock-socket';

it('test', () => {
        cy.visit('/', {onBeforeLoad(window) {
  cy.stub(window, 'WebSocket', url => {
  if (mockServer) {
    mockServer.stop();
  }
  mockServer = new Server(url);
  mockServer.on('connection', socket => {
    mockSocket = socket;
  });
  mockSocket = new WebSocket(url);
  return mockSocket;
});
```

My question is what is the object of ‘WebSocketLink’ that I need to stub (instead of window)? Or, is there another way to mock graphql web socket?